# Why acceptsFirstMouse not invoked in my custom nsview?

Tags: cocoa, nsview

Now i have a borderless window which i handle move and resize myself,but the window cannot be moved or resized when the window is deactive,after some reserach,i subclass a nsview and return YES to -acceptsFirstMouse:
But its never invoked.
Any one can help me?

Comment: Are you sure you overloaded exactly `- (BOOL)acceptsFirstMouse:(NSEvent *)theEvent` ?

Comment: Hey Gustav, very good -- you just fixed my issue. Dunno about NeXT5tep, but that was MY problem. :) I ranked your comment up.

Comment: I resolve it just replace the nsview with a nsbutton......